# Extraño problema al convertir un string enviado por PHP a JSON en JS

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Muy buenas a todos, Dios los bendiga!,
Sucede que estoy siguiendo un tutorial al pie de la letra pero estoy teniendo problemas a pesar de que copio todo como es, Estoy intentando enlistar todas las tareas que estan en la DB, La cual tiene los datos correctamente insertados, Tambien tengo la conexion correctamente ya que la he utilizado antes para insertar las nuevas tareas, Y bueno, el problema lo tengo al usar `JSON.parse();` en una peticion AJAX, Ya revise que el problema no fuera del servidor y vi que el codigo esta bien, Ya le he dado muchas vueltas y deseo que puedan ayudarme, Muchas gracias.

**Script DB**

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS php_tests;
USE php_tests;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tasks(
    ID          INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    Title       VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Description VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_tasks PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);
```

**Conexion a la DB**

```
<?php

$connection = mysqli_connect(
    'localhost',
    'root',
    'admin',
    'php_tests'
);
```

**Codigo del servidor que envia el array a el archivo JS**

```
<?php

require_once 'connection.php';

$query = "SELECT * FROM tasks";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

if (!$result) {
    die('Query Failed' . mysqli_error($connection));
}

$json = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    /* $json = array($row['ID'], $row['Title'], $row['Description']); */

    $json = array(
        'ID'=>$row['ID'],
        'Title'=>$row['Title'],
        'Description'=>$row['Description']
    );

    /* var_dump($json); */

    $jsonstring = json_encode($json);
    echo $jsonstring;
}
```

**Peticion AJAX (Archivo JS)**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'task_list.php',
    type: 'GET',
    success: (response) => {
        let tasks = JSON.parse(response);
        let template = '';

        tasks.forEach(task => {
            template += 
            `
            <tr>
                <td>${task.ID}</td>
                <td>${task.Title}</td>
                <td>${task.Description}</td>
            </tr>
            `;
        });
        $('#Tasks').html(template);
    }
});
```

**Error en consola**

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 79 of the JSON data
```

Comment: ¿Que error te da?

Comment: Disculpa el error @FranciscoGarrido, Ya lo agregue en la edicion :)

Comment: puedes dar ejemplos de los datos en BD y lo que intentas recuperar, comparado con lo que ahora mismo estás consiguiendo ?

Comment: Entonces los datos no estan llegando del todo bien. Prueba añadiendo esto al principio de tu archivo pvp `header('Content-Type: application/json');`. Tambien seria util que hicieras un console.log del response.

Comment: @FranciscoGarrido, El error desaparecio de consola pero ahora pareciera que no me llegaran los datos, Ya que nisiquiera puedo mostrar la respuesta del servidor mediante console.log(response)

Comment: @FranciscoGarrido y ahora que lo veo aun mas, Note que no sale respuesta alguna, Por lo tanto no alcanza ni a ejecutar la funcion Success

Comment: En el servidor dentro del while sólo estas cogiendo un dato, tedrías que cambiar los siguiente para coger todos los task: $json[] = array(..);

Comment: Deberías hacer un console.log en el succes y añadir dos funciones (de error y allways) al Ajax para comprobar que la función Ajax se esté ejecutando.

Comment: De hecho cuando tenía agregado $json[] los datos me salían duplicados, Y vi que al quitarle [] se mostraba correctamente el array asociativo, También comprobé el jsonstring y contenía todos los datos correctamente sin saltarse ni duplicar alguno

Comment: @JordiHuertas Al agregarle el Header mencionado más arribita al archivo php, La función success dejó de ejecutarse ya que no le está llegando respuesta del servidor, Pero sin el Header la función Json. parse se ejecuta y da error, Así que ya se esta sabiendo cuando funciona y cuando no el success

Comment: @Extibax es igual. Es una buena práctica y deberías tenerlo. Puede que te exté devolviendo o no un error de SyntaxError, pero no tiene por qué no estar ejecutando el Ajax. Igualmente este error me suena por dos motivos. El 1º es que, en el archivo php, estés dejando en la última línea un espacio o un salto de línea al cerrar (?>) php. El segundo es que el documento ajax no sea válido. Haz un var_dump en el php de $jsonstring y valídalo en https://jsonlint.com y nos actualizas la pregunta ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba realizando los siguientes cambios en el archivo php.

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

require_once 'connection.php';

$query = "SELECT * FROM tasks";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

if (!$result) {
    die('Query Failed' . mysqli_error($connection));
}

$json = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    /* $json = array($row['ID'], $row['Title'], $row['Description']); */

    $json[] = $row;

    /* var_dump($json); */


}

$jsonstring = json_encode($json);
echo $jsonstring;

?>
```

Y estos en el archivo JS.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'task_list.php',
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: (response) => {
        let tasks = response;
        let template = '';

        tasks.forEach(task => {
            template += 
            `
            <tr>
                <td>${task.ID}</td>
                <td>${task.Title}</td>
                <td>${task.Description}</td>
            </tr>
            `;
        });
        $('#Tasks').html(template);
    }
});
```

Así nos aseguramos de que el archivo PHP envía un JSON y que el JS es lo que espera. Ademas, no es necesario parsear a JSON ya que este viene listo.

Comment: Segui las recomendaciones de los dos y ahora ya entra a la funcion success pero ahora el console error es este:

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Comment: pon un `console.log(response);` antes del JSON.parse, para que te salga por la consola el resultado que te llega al ajax, y asi vemos si tiene mal formato lo que llega, ok?

Comment: Entonces creo que no te hace falta usar el JSON.parse(). Ya deberia estar parseado

Comment: @FranciscoGarrido, Y tu respuesta fue la correcta! Muchas gracias, Tambien tenia mi duda sobre por que pareciera estar convirtiendo a JSON 2 veces en el tutorial, Francisco, Escribe o modifica una respues para marcarla como correcta, Muchas gracias! Dios te bendiga :)

Comment: Claro, ya esta modificada explicando un poco los puntos

Answer (score 1):

Por cada petición de Ajax necesitas obtener un resultado y en el caso en el que has puesto estas haciendo un `echo` por cada dato de los `task` que obtienes. Prueba a sacar el `encode` y el `echo` fuera del `while`.

```
<?php

require_once 'connection.php';

$query = "SELECT ID, Title, Description FROM tasks";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

if (!$result) {
    die('Query Failed' . mysqli_error($connection));
}

$json = mysqli_fetch($result);

$jsonstring = json_encode($json);
echo $jsonstring;
```

Además si te traes la consulta con los tres datos que necesitas no es necesario crear un array con los datos obtenidos en la consulta.

Comment: Gracias por el recorte en cuanto al array del JSON, EN vez de usar var_dump use echo, copie el JSON lo valide en la pagina que compartiste y salio correcto,Cerre y saque del bucle While a $jsonstring como lo dijieron y ahora si entro a la funcion success, Pero ahora el console error es otro:

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Comment: El fecj_array te trae en formato array y con el cambio que he hecho te trae un obtjeto, prueba a ver si te funciona.